# is twice calls to copy constructor happen for this c++ code sample?

Tags: c++

for method:

```
Object test(){
    Object str("123");
    return str;
}
```

then, I had two methods to call it:

code 1:

```
const Object &object=test();
```

code 2:

```
Object object=test();
```

which one is better? is twice calls to copy constructor happen in code 2 if without optimize?

other what's the difference?

for code2 I suppose:

```
Object tmp=test();
Object object=tmp;
```

for code1 I suppose:

```
Object tmp=test();
Object &object=tmp;
```

but the tmp will be deconstructor after the method.so it must add const?

is code 1 right without any issues?

Comment: Unless you've profiled that this is slowing you down significantly, I'd say this is premature optimization. Just go with `string s = test();`, (N)RVO should kick in and make this a non issue anyway.

Comment: You could put a printf in the copy constructor of some test code and find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyse your function:

> ```
> Object test()
> {
>     Object temp("123");
>     return temp;
> }
> ```

Here you're constructing a local variable named `temp` and returning it from the function. The return type of `test()` is `Object` meaning you're returning by value. Returning local variables by value is a good thing because it allows a special optimization technique called Return Value Optimization (RVO) to take place. What happens is that instead of invoking a call to the copy or move constructor, the compiler will elide that call and directly construct the initializer into the address of the caller. In this case, because `temp` has a name (is an lvalue), we call it N(amed)RVO.

Assuming optimizations take place, no copy or move has been performed yet. This is how you would call the function from `main`:

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     Object obj = test();
> }
> ```

That first line in main seems to be of particular concern to you because you believe that the temporary will be destroyed by the end of the full expression. I'm assuming it is a cause for concern because you believe `obj` will not be assigned to a valid object and that initializing it with a reference to `const` is a way to keep it alive.

You are right about two things:

- The temporary will be destroyed at the end of the full expression
- Initializing it with a reference to `const` will extend its life time

But the fact that the temporary will be destroyed is not a cause for concern. Because the initializer is an rvalue, its contents can be *moved* from.

> ```
> Object obj = test(); // move is allowed here
> ```

Factoring in copy-elision, the compiler will elide the call to the copy or move constructor. Therefore, `obj` will be initialized "as if" the copy or move constructor was called. So because of these compiler optimizations, we have very little reason to fear multiple copies.

---

But what if we entertain your other examples? What if instead we had qualified `obj` as:

> ```
> Object const& obj = test();
> ```

`test()` returns a prvalue of type `Object`. This prvalue would normally be destructed at the end of the full expression in which it is contained, but because it is being initialized to a reference to `const`, its lifetime is extended to that of the reference.

What are the differences between this example and the previous one?:

- You cannot modify the state of `obj`
- **It inhibits move semantics**

The first bullet point is obvious but not the second if you are unfamiliar with move semantics. Because `obj` is a reference to `const`, it cannot be moved from and the compiler cannot take advantage of useful optimizations. Assigning reference to `const` to an rvalue is only helpful in a narrow set of circumstances (as DaBrain has pointed out). It is instead preferable that you exercise value-semantics and create value-typed objects when it makes sense.

Moreover, you don't even need the function `test()`, you can simply create the object:

> ```
> Object obj("123");
> ```

but if you do need `test()`, you can take advantage of type deduction and use `auto`:

> ```
> auto obj = test();
> ```

Your last example deals with an lvalue-reference:

> [..] but the `tmp` will be destructed after the method. So must we add `const`?
>
> ```
> Object &object = tmp;
> ```

The destructor of `tmp` is **not** called after the method. Taking in to account what I said above, the temporary to which `tmp` is being initialized will be moved into `tmp` (or it will be elided). `tmp` itself doesn't destruct until it goes out of scope. So no, there is no need to use `const`.

But a reference is good if you want to refer to `tmp` through some other variable. Otherwise, if you know you will not need `tmp` afterwards, you can move from it:

> ```
> Object object = std::move(tmp);
> ```

Comment: If my answer is missing something or can be improved, please feel free to comment.

Comment: very elaborate and kind answer!

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, `std::string` has a move constructor / move assignment operator, hence the code:

```
string str = test();
```

will (at worst) have one constructor call and one move assignment call.

Even without move semantics, this will (likely) be optimised away by NRVO (return value optimisation).

Don't be afraid of returning by value, basically.

Edit: Just to make it 100% clear what is going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class object
{
    std::string s;

public:

    object(const char* c) 
      : s(c)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }

    ~object() 
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }

    object(const object& rhs)
      : s(rhs.s)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
    }

    object& operator=(const object& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Assignment\n";
        s = rhs.s;
        return *this;
    }

    object& operator=(object&& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Move Assignment\n";
        s = std::move(rhs.s);
        return *this;
    }

    object(object&& rhs)
      : s(std::move(rhs.s))
    {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor\n";
    }
};

object test()
{
    object o("123");
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    object o = test();
    //const object& o = test();
}
```

You can see that there is 1 constructor call and 1 destructor call for each - NRVO kicks in here (as expected) eliding the copy/move.

Comment: what' more, I wang to know common behavior, so I update the question by changed the strong to object.

Comment: "Don't be afraid of returning by value" +3

Comment: but my method test doesn't return reference by copy, so even I assign to reference, is it ok?

Comment: The reference is `const`, so no UB here.

Answer (score 4):

Both your examples are valid - in 1 const reference refers to a temporary object, but lifetime of this object is prolonged till the reference goes out of scope (see http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). The second example is obviously valid, and most modern compilers will optimize away additional copying (even better if you use C+11 move semantics) so for practical purposes examples are equivalent (though in 2 additionally you can modify the value).

Comment: I wouldn't say equivalent. Only one of them gives you a value that you can modify. But you got the `const` reference thing right :)

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 is correct. As I said, the C++ Standard guarantees a temporary to a const reference is valid. It's main usage is polymorphic behavior with refenences:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base { public: virtual void Do() const { std::cout << "Base"; } };
class Derived : public Base { public: virtual void Do() const { std::cout << "Derived"; } };

Derived Factory() { return Derived(); }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const Base &ref = Factory();

    ref.Do();

    return 0;
}
```

This will return "Derived". A famouse example was Andrei Alexandrescu's ScopeGuard but with C++11 it's even simpler yet.